# Python: Connecting to db without any external libraries

Tags: python, database, oracle

I'm working on a client machine running suse linux and python 2.4.2. I'm not allowed to dowload anything from the net including any external libraries. So, is there any way I can connect to a database (oracle) using only the default libraries?

Comment: You need to have a talk with whom ever is placing such unreasonable restrictions on you.  "No external libraries"?  With all the great Python software out there, I can't understand.

Comment: Technically, you could write code that use tcp/ip sockets to speak the database's protocol, effectively implementing a new database client from scratch. It's even harder than I make it sound, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is nothing in the standard library for connecting to database servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [Apex Listener](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/overview/index.html) and/or PL/SQL Embedded Gateway (basically a webserver in the DB). These both provide HTTP access to database resources (eg [getting data as JSON)](http://krisrice.blogspot.com/2010/10/restjson-access-to-your-data-in-2.html). Though obviously this shifts the 'heavy lifting' to the database platform.